# Web3 Call Back Issue for Function - Solidity

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I am trying to connect a contract to my private RPC server. I would like to be able to update a counter parameter on my html page, which in turn references to my solidity contract file and updates on my browser. However, I keep running into the follow error for my html file below. index.html and contract.sol includes below too. TY!

[image]
index.html

```
<!doctype html>
        <html>
<head>
    <title>myDapp</title>
    <script src="web3.js/dist/web3.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">



        var contract_address = "0x68FDbd58D28BeD866E07906f6129bAC86161e243";
        var contract_abi = [ { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "getCreator", "outputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "address", "value": "0xc0f0fb70a63e7b345932da8eb427463f586be95d" } ], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [], "name": "kill", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [ { "name": "myNewNumber", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "setMyNumber", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "getMyNumber", "outputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "uint256", "value": "3" } ], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "constructor" } ];

        if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
            web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        } else {
            // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
            web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
        }

        var contract_instance = web3.eth.contract(contract_abi).at(contract_address);
        console.log(contract_instance);


        function getCounter() {
            document.getElementById("myCounter").innerText = contract_instance.getMyNumber().toNumber().call;

}


    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Interact with a contract</h1>

<button onclick="getCounter()">Update Counter</button>
<button onclick="increaseCounter()">Increase Counter</button>

<span id="myCounter"></span> Counter

</body>
</html>
```

contract.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;
contract MyContract {
    address creator;
    uint256 myNumber;

    function MyContract() public {
        creator = msg.sender;
        myNumber = 3;
    }

    function getCreator() public constant returns(address) {
        return creator;
    }

    function getMyNumber() public constant returns(uint256) {
        return myNumber;
    }

    function setMyNumber(uint256 myNewNumber) public {
        myNumber = myNewNumber;
    }

    function kill() public {
        if(msg.sender == creator) {
            selfdestruct(creator);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your trying to connect `Metamask` directly with `web3.js` that is not how you should do it. 
Metamask is based on [provider Engine](https://github.com/MetaMask/provider-engine) and provider eninge doesn't support synchronous functions or operations for example:

You can't do 
`web3.eth.accounts`

but you can do `web3.eth.getAcounts()`.

In order to work best its best to use provider engine to inject your web3 and take it from there, you will notice how in order to make things run you will switch everything to an async format.

but in all cases use web3.js asynchronous functions and you will get what you want.